# Js) what will be the simplest way to check null or '' as false but not 0?

Tags: javascript

I usually used `if(value)` to check value is null or not. But now I know `false` or `0` can be false. So I used `if(value == null)` but in this time, that null doesn't contain '' like.
I want to check that `0`, `false`(have specific value) as true, and I want to check that `''`, `undefined`, `null` as false
What will be good way to check these values simply? Is there something to notice bout like this more?

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/

Comment: `if (value === 0 || value === false)`…?

Comment: do you have a table of values and results?

Comment: Well, I want to check `0` and `false` also as truthy values, not `0` and `false` only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check for the possible values normally.

```js
const isFalsy = param => (param === null) || (param === "") || (typeof param === "undefined")

isFalsy(null); // true
isFalsy(0); // false
```

> I want to check that `0`, `false`(have specific value) as true.

```
if(!isFalsy(value))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this small helper function helps? Play with it in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-4f2faa?file=index.js).

```js
test();
test(42);
test(Infinity);
test(null);
test(0);
test({});
test(new Map());

function test(someValue) {
  if (hasValue(someValue)) {
    return console.log(`${someValue} is truthy`);
  }
  
  return console.log(`${someValue} is falsy`);
}  

function hasValue(v) {
  // Objects are always considered values
  if (v instanceof Object) {
    return true;
  }

  const falsies2Check = [false, 0, '', null, undefined, Infinity];
  
  return falsies2Check.find(f => f === v || isNaN(v)) === undefined ? true : false;
}
```